# Showing a UIActivityViewController with all custom actions

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm working in iOS 7, and I want to show a `UIActivityViewController` all with my custom activities and no built in activities. I know that I can use `excludesActivityTypes` and list all the constants that are defined, but is there a way to automatically exclude all system activities(but not my own)?

I would hate to list all the system activities in the call to that property, and then have my app break when iOS 7.2 or iOS 8 comes around and adds more built in activities.

Comment: It seems like you ought to be able to do this by passing `UIActivityItemSource` items into the activity controller instead of other objects.  Perhaps by returning nil from `activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem:` or one of the other methods.  You'd have to experiment some and see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly the API doesn't support this. You must list all activities for exclusion. Every iOS update you need to check to see if any new activities are available and update your app accordingly.

Submit an enhancement request to Apple to add support for a way to either exclude all activities or a way to specify which ones to include.

Comment: Someone here actually pointed out that I really shouldn't be using the activity controller anyway since I'm not using anything it was meant for(sharing between apps). So I rewrote this to avoid the activity controller. Thanks for the confirmation though.